# In Odoo, when purchasing a packaged product, only one package gets created

Tags: odoo, purchase-order

I created a product and configured the packing to 3 types of packages (containing 20, 50 and 100 units)

When I make a Purchase Order and receive the products and press on (Put in Pack), only one package gets created whatever the quantity is and whatever the package type is.

How to set Odoo to create multiple packages depending on the quantity and package?